# variable size rolling window regression

Tags: pandas

In Pandas OLS the window size is fix length. How can I achieve set the window size based on index instead of number of rows?

I have a series where it has variable number of observations per day and I have 10 years history of data, so I want to run rolling OLS on 1 year rolling window. loop through each date  is a bit too slow, anyway to make it faster? Here is the example of the data.

```
  Date     x      y
2008-1-2  10.0    2
2008-1-2  5.0     1
2008-1-3  7.0   1.5
2008-1-5  9.0   3.0
...
2013-5-30 11.0  2.5
```

I would like something simple like `pandas.ols(df.y, df.x, window='1y')`, rather than looping each row since it will be slow to do the loop.

Answer (score 3):

There is method for doing this in pandas see documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#computing-rolling-pairwise-correlations:

```
model = pandas.ols(y=df.y, x=df.x, window=250)
```

you will just have to provide your period is a number of intervals on frame instead of '1y'.  There are also many additional options that you might find useful on your data.

all the rolling ols statistics are in *model*

```
model.beta.plot()
```

to show rolling beta

Comment: This is not right answer. I know this function and the function doesn't work the way I described since in my case rolling window size can be different between day to day (more observations points in one day than the other).

Comment: understand... does that make sense mathematically though..   I would guess that having more sample points at some times (closely grouped in time) does not make that period more important than another with only 1 sample?

Comment: depending on your data's applicability of previous comment you can use resampling to fixed periods using... definitely not filling blanks if you are feeding it to ols

Comment: yes, that is what I did(make sure every day has same number of observations). The only problem is in order to ensure accuracy, the resampled data has to be equal to the mean of rolling window mean, this is slow process. This is why I think if there is way to specify window by index, that will be preferable.

Comment: from pandas documentation it does noe seem that there is a way to do it without manual slicing/ iteration i used a generator to to do do something similar ( mith matrix alegra) but obviously takes performance hit.  Let's see if anybody has a way of coercing the pandas method to do it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the way.. I had no idea that pandas.ols supports window natively.